# Como incluir biblioteca de "time" no compilador?

Tags: c, osx, time, header

Estou compilando em C no meu Mac pelo terminal, esta tudo uma maravilha, o único problema é que quando eu preciso chamar uma biblioteca nova eu não sei qual o comando para chamá-la pelo terminal.

Ex: `#include <stdio.h>` é `-std=c99`

Eu não sei onde eu posso achar as versões de terminal de chamada de funções, agora eu estou tentando chamar a biblioteca `time.h` sem sucesso pois se eu tento algo do tipo `-time` não compila, sabem onde encontro essas informações?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Você tem que usar `#include <time.h>` dentro do seu código. Isto deve bastar porque tanto o cabeçalho quanto a biblioteca propriamente dita estão no mesmo lugar da outra que você já usou e deu certo.

O `-std=c99` nada tem a ver com o `include`.

Comment: Então, eu tentei sem chamar, mas aconteceu o que eu previ, ele não reconhece as coisas que usam o time.h pq não ta no terminal quando eu compilo, ao compilar com o terminal não basta eu chamar no include. Estou fazendo um jogo no Allegro e para todas as funções que usam outras bibliotecas eu tenho que, alem de chamar a função no código, eu tenho q chama-la ao compilar se não ele não reconhece. As bibliotecas do allegro tinham nomes fáceis de se tirar tendo como referencia o header ai eu não tive problemas.

Comment: Você deve estar usando o compilador de forma errada mas não passou o erro, nem exatamente o que fez com todos os detalhes, então não sei como te ajudar. Eu respondi o que dava pra responder de acordo com a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

(como o @Maniero já respondeu) em princípio `cc -o exemplo exemplo.c` chegaria para este caso.

algumas notas (alguns detalhes podem variar com o sistema operativo):

1. Normalmente, `time.h` (assim como os outros ficheiros `.h`) contem apenas as declarações de funções (e de alguns tipos), não as definem. Portanto, não são as bibliotecas mas apenas declarações.
   As definições destas funções estão contidas na biblioteca base do C (algo como libc) juntamente com mais umas centenas de outras funções.
2. quando necessitamos de funções que não pertencem à biblioteca do C
   (exemplo algumas `sqrt()`), incluiremos a sua declaração (#include ) e juntamos a respectiva biblioteca (`-lm`) a linha de compilação.
   Quando o compilador encontra p `-lm` vai procurar a biblioteca (`.../libm.a` ou `.so` ou coisa parecida) que contem a definição já compilada dessas funções.
3. o `-std=c99` (que como o @Maniero tinha dito pouco influencia esta questão) apenas altera o tipo avisos, o conjunto de extensões que vão
   ser toleradas pelo compilador.